# Obj-C equivalent for mdfind?

Tags: objective-c, spotlight

Is there a way to do a Spotlight query, in Obj-C, similar to what `mdfind` does? I need to write a method with the following signature:

```
-(NSString *)mdfind:(NSString *)theFileToLookFor
```

where the returned `NSString` is the first path found by the search.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: [Check this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674688/mac-spotlight-api-how-to-search-emails-to-from-or-subject-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the apis are in CoreServices.framework. start with the ones which have the prefix `MDQuery`

Answer (score 2):

[`NSMetadataQuery`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the wrapper around the Carbon-level [`MDQuery`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDQueryRef/Reference/reference.html) API, which is how one interacts with the user's spotlight database.